# How can I check if a index in an array is empty and how to shift an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

I have this function for a Go Fish Card game.

// Remove a Card from the player's hand

// In:  _index      The index of the card to remove from the array

//      _discard        A reference to store that value in

//
// Return: True if there was a card actually stored at that index.

//         False if the index was "empty"

```
bool Player::Discard(int _index, Card& _discard)
{
        return true;
}
```

Should store the requested card into the reference being passed in.
After that, "shift" the array back to show this card has been removed.

Example:
[ 7♥ 3♣ 5♦ 9♥ ]     m_numCards: 4

- discarding index 1 (the 3♣) *

[ 7♥ 5♦ 9♥ 9♥ ]     m_numCards: 3

- Even though it looks like there are two 9♥, we won't ever be displaying  that to the user, and it will be the first one that gets overwritten if 
   another card is added to the hand. **/

  // Just here for compilation

in the header i have this member variables.

```
char m_name[32];    
Card m_hand[7];
int m_numCards; 
int m_maxCards; 
int m_score;
```

I had this inside to do the first part But im pretty sure im missing something.

```
      if (m_hand[_index] != FALSE)
{
    _discard = m_hand[_index];
    return true;
}
else 
    return false;
```

Comment: Instead of using an array you could use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) that have erase methods that will handle doing that or you.

Comment: List is always a better option when dealing with such problems

Comment: somebody in other forums mentioned this but i havent touched that subject yet so Im not sure i Can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your "hand" as an array:

```
Card m_hand[7];
```

Then you always have 7 cards. Sure you could add a "sentinel" `Card` value or something, but really there's always 7 cards. You can't remove or append to a raw array. On the other hand, if you used a dynamic container instead:

```
std::vector<Card> m_hand;
```

Now, you *can* have a variable-sized hand and add and remove cards as you see fit. And your discard function becomes easy:

```
bool Player::Discard(int _index, Card& _discard)
{
    if (m_hand.size() > _index) {
        _discard = m_hand[_index];
        m_hand.erase(m_hand.begin() + _index);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Although with Go Fish, it probably makes more sense to discard a card by value:

```
bool Player::Discard(Card const& card)
{
    size_t cur = m_hand.size();
    m_hand.erase(std::remove(m_hand.begin(), m_hand.end(), card), m_hand.end());
    return m_hand.size() != cur;
}
```

Comment: when I put this I get a warning, it does everything how it suppose to but i get a  warning

Comment: @M.Lugo When you put **what**, you get **what** warning?

Comment: what library should i include for the vector keyword?

Comment: @M.Lugo Did you even try to search for the answer? Also, `vector` is not a keyword, and failing to include the correct file wouldn't cause a warning, it would cause a compile error.

Comment: alright every forum I asked this have said something about the vector thing, but i havent touch that subject in class  so I dont know what im doing when applying it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 52 cards in a standard deck and an unsigned char can represent more than 52 distinct values.

Assign zero as a 'no card' value and use values 1 - 52 to represent the cards. Instead of removing cards from the array and then rearranging it, simply overwrite the value to be erased with zero.

When adding a card to the array, iterate until you find an index where the value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I figured it out

```
bool Player::Discard(int _index, Card& _discard)
{
   if (_index < m_numCards)
{
    _discard = m_hand[_index];

    for (int i = _index + 1; i < m_numCards; ++i)
    {
        m_hand[i - 1] = m_hand[i];
    }
    m_numCards -= 1;
    return true;
      }
       else
    return false;

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Answer (score -1):

Even though this is probably homework assignment, you should really use built-in methods in objects such as `std::vector` or `std::list`. If you really want to use arrays, you can delete an element by moving all elements to the left that are *after* the element you want to delete. It would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardsLength; i ++) {
    if (cards[i] == theCardYouWantToDelete) {
        for (int j = i; j < cardsLength - 1; j ++) {
            cards[j] = cards[j + 1];
        }
        break; // to break out of outer for loop
    }
}
```

Comment: would this take care of the shifting only?

Comment: No, it will take care of "deletion" aswell! Using your examples, if cards are [7, 3, 5, 9] and you want to delete the second card (which is a three), it will copy card number 5 over the card number three, and you will have an array of: [7, 5, 5, 9]. In the next iteration it will copy number nine over (the second) number five, and the array would be: [7, 5, 9, 9]. Try to follow the loop step by step, using paper, and you will notice how it works in a matter of minutes. Edit: Also notice the cardsLength - 1"! That prevents the code from executing: cards[cardsLength" which is illegal. Good luck.